# Why does line-through work only for every other item on this jQuery to do list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a jQuery to do list in which i want to be able to add an item, then click on a checkbox to add a line-through. Finally when i click on the trash button, the appended item should be removed.
The code works fine as long as i add just one item, add a line-through, and then delete the item.
If more items are added, i can still add and remove items but line-through does not work for every item. It seems like i can only select even or odd-numbered items for line-through.
My code follows and here is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/mansieh/project/editor/ZBabkg/). 
As a newbie to the coding world, your help is much appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--link for the font-awesome garbage bin icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 class="title">To Do List</h1>
        <form class="form-box">
            <input type="text" class="input-box" placeholder="Add An Item to Your To Do List" onclick="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Add An Item to Your To Do List'" > 
            <button  type="submit" value="Add" class="input-button" name="input-button">Add</button>
        </form>
        <!-- A couple of commented-out sample divs that would be added on when <button> is clicked (see app.js)-->
        <!--<div class="item-box">
            <h3 class="item-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-box">
            <h3 class="item-text strikethrough">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->     
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- End of JAVASCRIPT -->  
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-button").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var value = $(".input-box").val();
        var item = "<div class='item-box'> <h3 class='item-text'>" + value + "</h3> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'> <i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button' aria-hidden='true'></i> </div>";
        $(".main").append(item);
        $(".bin-button").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        $(".checkbox").click(function() {
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("strikethrough");
        });
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #666;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    margin: 20px;
}

.title {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.form-box {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    height: auto;
}

.input-box {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
}

.input-button {
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

/* styling for div items added through jQuery */

.item-box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
}

.item-box h3, input, i {
    display: inline-block;
}

.item-box h3 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.item-box input {
    margin-top: 18.5px;
}

.item-box i {
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.item-box input, i {
    float: right;

}

.bin-button {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Typography */

h1.title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

h3.item-text {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

h3.strikethrough {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the checkbox's click function outside of the scope of the input box's click function. Also, because your checkboxes are dynamically generated, you will want to use the following syntax:

```
$(document).on('click','.checkbox',function() {
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("strikethrough");
}
```

Therefore, your full JQuery code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-button").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var value = $(".input-box").val();
        var item = "<div class='item-box'> <h3 class='item-text'>" + value + "</h3> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'> <i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button' aria-hidden='true'></i> </div>";
        $(".main").append($(item));
    }); 
    $(document).on("click", ".bin-button", function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
        $(this).prev().toggleClass("strikethrough");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're re-registering many, many events with this bit of code:

```
    $(".bin-button").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    $(".checkbox").click(function() {
      ...
    });
```

So for each todo added, the number of events registered to that checkbox will increase.

For example: 1st todo, life is good and one event is registered.  2nd todo itself will work fine, but the first todo now has two events bound to the checkbox.  This means toggleClass is called twice.

For example, doing somethign like this will show that the click events are triggered many times:

```
let called = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-button").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var value = $(".input-box").val();
        var item = "<div class='item-box'> <h3 class='item-text'>" + value + "</h3> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'> <i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button' aria-hidden='true'></i> </div>";
        $(".main").append(item);
        $(".bin-button").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        $(".checkbox").click(function() {
      called++;
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("strikethrough");
      console.log(called);
        });
    }); 
});
```

You could instead create the the element using `$(item)` and appending the click events to that element before adding it to the dom.  For example:

```
let called = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".input-button").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var value = $(".input-box").val();
        var item = $("<div class='item-box'> <h3 class='item-text'>" + value + "</h3> <input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'> <i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x bin-button' aria-hidden='true'></i> </div>");
    item.find(".bin-button").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    item.find(".checkbox").click(function() {
      called++;
            $(this).prev().toggleClass("strikethrough");
      console.log(called);
        });
        $(".main").append(item);
    }); 
});
```